# Float division eliminating rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, floating-point

I have a table with 4 main columns: Store, TotalCustomers, and TotalCustomers30, with 'TotalCustomers30' indicating the # of customers 30 days ago. This query returns 10,000 rows:

```
select Store,
       CAST(TotalCustomers as float) as TotalCustomers,
       CAST(TotalCustomers30 as float) as TotalCustomers30,
       CAST(TotalCustomers - TotalCustomers30) as float) as diff
from Purchases
```

I am trying to calculate % change in customers by doing the following:

```
select *, CAST(((ISNULL(diff,0)/ISNULL(TotalCustomers30,0))as float) AS percchange
from (
    select Store,
           CAST(TotalCustomers as float) as TotalCustomers,
           CAST(TotalCustomers30 as float) as TotalCustomers30,
           CAST(TotalCustomers - TotalCustomers30) as float) as diff
    from Purchases) a
```

This second query only returns 20 rows. There doesn't appear to be anything weird or unique with the rows that are returning.  Anyone have any idea why this could be?

Comment: What is your desired result when `TotalCustomers30` is NULL or zero? Almost surely, dividing by zero doesn't yield the result you want.

Comment: This can't be.  Nothing in your queries would reduce the number of rows.  Perhaps the data changed or you are using different queries.

Comment: Adding "WHERE totalCustomers iS NOT NULL or TotalCustomers30 IS NOT NULL" doesn't change the result -- I still only get 20 rows

Comment: I agree with @GordonLinoff. There are no predicates or aggregation anywhere. There must be something else in your script that you are running and not showing us.